# Is there a way to disable onscroll event from preventing page from full scroll, wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, themes

Please can anyone help me concerning wordpress on how to disable onscroll from theme homepage not able to scroll very well, I want full scroll no stopping just full scroll please if anyone can help thanks.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what theme, plugins and custom code you are using to have your current scroll?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard without seeing any code, but if I have to guess putting this at the top of the page before any other Javascript might work.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, will try that thanks. The theme name is Portus by orange theme